# meaning of Kill the game

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

What does "kill" mean in the phrase "kill the game?"

> Christian Eriksen
>
> It hasn’t been beautiful for 90 minutes but we have three wins. We
> want to do better but it’s a good start. It was similar to Southampton
> – we have to **kill the game** earlier, otherwise it will be tight at the
> end. The games keep coming – Thursday/Sunday until after the World
> Cup.

Comment: Sounds like winning intensively. Killing a song means performing it to the limit...very well. Compare it to "Cold as Hell" for surprising uses of *kill* and *cold*.

Comment: So, "Kill the game" means to perfome the game, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, to play it so well as to *slaughter* the opponent.

Comment: Specifically, take control and get enough goals/points that the opponent has no chance of coming back, and the game is no longer **live**. There are relevant meanings of **[live](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live)** such as "in play" ("a live ball"), "of continuing or current interest" ("a live topic").

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is clear in your context.

He wants to finish off the game earlier.